# Google Analytics gtag where to find custom config key value pairs

Tags: google-analytics

where would I find my custom key/value pairs which are I passed through my gtag config in my Analytics dashboard?

For example, I want to filter data by the key `customKey` here:

```
<script>
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
            gtag('config', 'XXXXXX', {'customKey': 'value'});
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it seems [the reference only discusses briefly the commands](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/references/tracking-snippet-reference) (`event`,`config`,`set`).

Most of the actual `customKey` options seem to be discussed under the [Guide's **Advanced Tracking** section](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/) (see left-hand sidebar) on a per-topic basis. For instance:

[**Cookies and user identification**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cookies-user-id)

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {
  'cookie_name': 'gaCookie',
  'cookie_domain': 'blog.example.co.uk',
  'cookie_expires': 2419200  // 28 days, in seconds
});
```

[**Custom dimensions and metrics**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets)

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {
  'custom_map': {'dimension<Index>': 'dimension_name'}
});
```

[**IP anonymization**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/ip-anonymization)

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
```

etc...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I actually used the custom dimension in the end which did the trick! Just had to create the custom dimension in the Google Analytics dashboard and then create the custom_map like you have above and it all tied together.

Comment: You're welcome. I had read your question too quickly: indeed for custom text/numeric values you want to use dimensions/metrics (you also have calculated metrics to make operations between existing and custom metrics: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6121409?hl=en). Don't forget to upvote and select the answer if you're happy with it so the rest of the community can benefit from it :)